# Is it possible to connect active JBL speakers using unbalanced cable to pre-outs on amp?

Tags: speakers, xlr, rca

I have active JBL 308P MKII speakers, they have XLR and TRS inputs. I wish to connect them to the pre-out (L + R channels) on my Monitor Audio A100 streamer/amp.

I am wondering if it's possible to do so using an unbalanced male XLR to male RCA cable or male TS to RCA. This cable would run from pre-out on the A100 to the respective input on the speakers. I would use one of the below cables for each speaker.

Also, as I understand the pre-outs are not like standard line-out and have variable voltage? Hence why I have doubts it would work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes. It will work.

Longer answer, not the full story though:

Connect from the RCA preamp outputs. I believe you can control the volume out somehow in the amp. If not, you will want to add some kind of volume control.

Connect to the inputs of the speakers. You can try different settings for the "sensitivity" of the speakers. My guess is that -10dBv setting will work best.

You might find a less costly cable by going from RCA to mono TS connector (or TRS), it will work as well as the XLR.

Generally, it is possible to connect balanced and unbalanced to each other using the correct cable. When you run long cable runs balanced gives an edge in resistance to induced mains hum ( and 2x mains frequency). Additionally balanced has 6dB more output compared to unbalanced when running at professional level +4dBu, but that can generally be adjusted for. Consumer RCA outputs has even lower outputs, hence the switch on the speakers for -10dBv to accept consumer level.

Comment: And long answer?

Comment: Added a bit for a longer answer.